# What does dataset %>% rename(!!vars) mean in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I am new to R. So when I read some R code, I could not understand what the symbol means, such as `!!` in the code `dataset %>% rename(!!vars)`.
Could someone help me on this?  Thanks.

Comment: Easiest place to start is from `?\`!!\``

Comment: There is extensive documentation on [tidyeval](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/sec-up-to-speed.html) and the use of `!!` in [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: Tried ? '!!' and it really shows me the answer! Super.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bang bang operator `!!` from the `rlang` package forces early evaluation of an object. Within the `tidyverse` family of packages it is used to enable variable substitution in code pipelines.

```
aVariable <- sym("mpg")

library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>%
     summarise(mean = mean(!!aVariable))
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     am  mean
* <dbl> <dbl>
1     0  17.1
2     1  24.4
>
```

For additional details on forcing functions, read [rlang nse-force](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/nse-force.html).

Comment: Thanks so much for answering my question. I was afraid that I might asked a too silly question. :P

Comment: @Stataq - you're welcome. One of the challenges with the `tidyverse` family of packages is that some tasks that are easy in base R are more complicated in the `tidyverse`, especially for beginners. Norman Matloff addresses this in his essay, [Tidyverse Skeptic](https://github.com/matloff/TidyverseSkeptic).

Answer (score 3):

Stataq,

For a newbie, you've wandered into some deep water.  `!!` is part of Non-Standard-Evaluation (NSE).  It's an advanced topic, and it's covered in Hadley Wickham's *Advanced R*, in the *MetaProgramming* section: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/metaprogramming.html

Unless you're familiar with NSE from some other computer language - you'll find it a steep learning curve.  Is there a problem you can't solve right now unless you understand `!!` ?